# MYSQL _ Replace?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.

| Table A |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id (key) | name | date | tel |
| 1 | Adam | 2021/05/30 | 5552345 |
| 2 | Bronwyn | 2021/04/21 | 5557890 |
| 3 | Peet | 2021/03/12 | 5555677 |

| Table B |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id (key) | hair | eyes | tel |
| 1 | blond | blond | 5552345 |
| 2 | brown | green | 5557890 |
| 3 | red | green | 5555677 |

| Table C |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id (key) | name | tel | shirt | hair | eyes |
| 1 | Adam | 5552345 | blue | blond | blond |
| 2 | Bronwyn | 5557890 | red | brown | green |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |

Now if I need to add in Table C Peet with shirt = green, I can just do a insert and use inner joins to get data from Table A and Table B

| Table C |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id (key) | name | tel | shirt | hair | eyes |
| 3 | Peet | 5555677 | green | red | green |

But I am not sure if the Peet information is in the table or not, so it should be a update or replace statement?

Can you use inner join with replace?

Comment: it is useful to know more aboit your tables, for the INSERT ON DUPLICATE to wirk you need soem columns that are unique so that the system know ift must update the resst. So if you want only one Peet with green shirt you make a UNIQUE constraint with name and shirt.

Comment: The shirt is unique in table C and I only want on Peet in table C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like i said in the comment, you need a UNIQUE constraint so that Mysql knows when it has to update the row

With `UNIQUE(`name`)` every time MySQL finds a Peet in the insert statement it will update all other olumns `tel`, `shirt`, `hair`, `eyes` with the provided new data

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TableC (
>   `id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>   `name` VARCHAR(7),
>   `tel` INTEGER,
>   `shirt` VARCHAR(10),
>   `hair` VARCHAR(10),
>   `eyes` VARCHAR(10),
>   UNIQUE(`name`)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO TableC
>   (`id`, `name`, `tel`, `shirt`, `hair`, `eyes`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Adam', '5552345', 'blue', 'blond', 'blond'),
>   ('2', 'Bronwyn', '5557890', 'red', 'brown', 'green');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO TableC (`name`, `tel`, `shirt`, `hair`, `eyes`)
> VALUEs ('Peet',   5555677,    'green',    'red' , 'green')
> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tel` = VALUES(`tel`) , `shirt`= VALUES(`shirt`)
> , `hair` = VALUES(`hair`) , `eyes` = VALUES(`eyes`)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO TableC (`name`, `tel`, `shirt`, `hair`, `eyes`)
> VALUEs ('Peet',   5555677,    'red',  'red' , 'green')
> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tel` =VALUES(`tel`) , `shirt`= VALUES(`shirt`)
> , `hair` = VALUES(`hair`) , `eyes` = VALUES(`eyes`)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM TableC
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name    |     tel | shirt | hair  | eyes 
> -: | :------ | ------: | :---- | :---- | :----
>  1 | Adam    | 5552345 | blue  | blond | blond
>  2 | Bronwyn | 5557890 | red   | brown | green
>  3 | Peet    | 5555677 | red   | red   | green
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8bb2d5c8dcc50b49f984fb9340795974)*

Comment: Thank you, you were a great help

Comment: Can you please score my question? As you answer did help me and the system have now blocked me as the AI perceives I am not contributing.